# Using graphviz to read .mtx format

Tags: python, graphviz

I use the following code for graphviz to read a market graph format (.mtx).

```
from graphviz import Source
path = '/path/to/dot_file'
s = Source.from_file(path)
s.view()
```

The format is described [here](http://networkrepository.com/mtx-matrix-market-format.html) and I wrote this content

```
4 4 6  
2 1  
3 1  
3 2  
4 1  
4 2  
4 3
```

However, I get this error:

```
    s.view()
  File "/home/mahmood/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graphviz/files.py", line 242, in view
    quiet=quiet, quiet_view=quiet_view)
  File "/home/mahmood/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graphviz/files.py", line 209, in render
    quiet=quiet)
  File "/home/mahmood/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graphviz/backend.py", line 221, in render
    run(cmd, capture_output=True, cwd=cwd, check=True, quiet=quiet)
  File "/home/mahmood/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graphviz/backend.py", line 184, in run
    output=out, stderr=err)
graphviz.backend.CalledProcessError: Command '['dot', '-Tpdf', '-O', 'graph.mtx']' returned non-zero exit status 1 [stderr: "Error: graph.mtx: syntax error in line 1 near '4'\n"]
```

It is supposed that graphviz supports `.mtx` format. How can I fix that then? Any more option should I specify?

Comment: The link you provided [The Matrix Market File Format](http://networkrepository.com/mtx-matrix-market-format.html) indicates that you need the `%MatrixMarket` header line.

Comment: No that doesn't matter. it is a comment. With that, I get `[stderr: "Error: graph.mtx: syntax error in line 1 near '%'\n"]`

Comment: I looked in the graphviz documentation, and could not find any indication that it actually can read Market Matrix graph files. The command-line help for `dot` actually states that the input files are `<dot files>` (i.e., written in the `dot` language).

Answer (score 2):

`graphviz` does not support direct reading of Market Matrix graph files. The [Source](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#graphviz.Source) documentation does not include reference to direct reading of MTX files, and neither does the command-line documentation of the `dot` program (used under the hood by your code/the API).

The `graphviz` library&tools installation on Linux (version 2.40.1) does include a program called `mm2gv` which converts MTX files to `dot` language. I did not see any reference to invoking this tool through the Python `graphviz` API, so I guess your best bet is to manually invoke this tool as a sub-process. You can probably even pipe its output to the `Source` object you are building.